# Switching from Luma to Blank not working

Tags: magento2, theme

I tried to switch default theme from Luma to Blank by going to **Content** > **Configuration** and editing the 3 records to Blank theme as you can see :

[image]

Then I erased Browser cache, restarted apache and mysql, and reload the Home page, but it still the Luma Theme:

[image]

Comment: You have to run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run below command,

```
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Remove **var/view_preprocessed** folder

clear cache.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by "clear cache" you mean the cache of my browser ?

Comment: Clear browser cache and run cache command php bin/magento cache:clean

Answer (score 1):

> Remove folders from Var directory (cache, generation and page_cache)
>   then use following commands in CLI(from magento 2 root): -

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

> then refresh page and you will have all css applied.

Answer (score 0):

Use these command under magento2 root directory

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```